# Normalize data using look-up table R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
COMM    YEAR    PRODUCE
Apple   2001    3
Mango   2001    5
Apple   2002    7
Mango   2002    2
Apple   2003    1
Mango   2003    9
```

I also have a yearly production dataframe:

```
Year Total.Produce
2001 10
2002 13
2003 14
```

I want to add a new column to the first data-frame that contains the normalized production of each item per year:

```
COMM    YEAR    PRODUCE  Normalized.Produce
Apple   2001    3        3/10
Mango   2001    5        5/10
Apple   2002    7        7/13
Mango   2002    2        2/13
Apple   2003    9        9/14
Mango   2003    2        2/14
```

What is the most effecient R way of doing this?
My tables contains about 100,000 entries.

Comment: Tons of ways. Take a look at `?merge` and `?match` for instance. Try `df$PRODUCE/lookup$Total.Produce[match(df$YEAR,lookup$Year)]`, where `df` is the "big" dataset and `lookup` the one with the totals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `match` to get the matching rows:

```
R> match(dd1$YEAR, dd2$Year)
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Then just use standard vectorised commands:

```
dd1$normalise = dd1$PRODUCE/dd2$Total.Produce[match(dd1$YEAR, dd2$Year)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also use the `merge` function.

```
d1 <- read.table(text=
"COMM    YEAR    PRODUCE
Apple   2001    3
Mango   2001    5
Apple   2002    7
Mango   2002    2
Apple   2003    1
Mango   2003    9", head=T, as.is=T)

d2 <- read.table(text="Year Total.Produce
2001 10
2002 13
2003 14", head=T, as.is=T)

d3 <- merge(d1, d2, by.x="YEAR", by.y="Year")
d3$Normalized.Produce <- d3$PRODUCE/d3$Total.Produce
#   YEAR  COMM PRODUCE Total.Produce Normalized.Produce
# 1 2001 Apple       3            10         0.30000000
# 2 2001 Mango       5            10         0.50000000
# 3 2002 Apple       7            13         0.53846154
# 4 2002 Mango       2            13         0.15384615
# 5 2003 Apple       1            14         0.07142857
# 6 2003 Mango       9            14         0.64285714
```